# How to send a print job to another computer?

Tags: debian, windows, printing

The IT technician at my workplace said that policy is to allow people to bring their own devices to work, but that IT cannot do any work on those devices. I brought my laptop with Debian installed, so that I can get much more work done. But because of this policy, administrators will not give me the password for the printers, so I cannot print any files.

My alternative has been to: (1) save the file to PDF; (2) E-mail the file to myself; (3) check my E-mail on the workplace-provided Windows machines; (4) download the file and (5) print from there. This is time-consuming.

Is there any other method of printing that would require fewer steps?

Comment: @terdon I just wondered if there was a way to simplify or speed up the steps of sending the file to the Windows machine, as the Windows machine is setup to print.

Comment: Ah. In that case, please [edit] your question to clarify. You might want to remove all of the first paragraph since it isn't really relevant. All we need to know is that you need to send the file to the Windows computer in order to print. Everything else is distracting (as you can see by all my irrelevant comments). Also, give us more details about your network. Are the two machines on the same network? If so, you could set up your Windows machine to download any new files from a directory of your Linux one. But we'd need more details about your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how locked down your Windows machines are, you might not be able to run programs on them. If you can run a program on it, you might be able to set something up using a USB cable.

Otherwise, assuming that they're located on the same LAN (otherwise there'd be no way you could get into the printer even with a password) you could set up a webserver and faux printer on your laptop. The printer simply "prints" a PDF to a web-served directory that you have write permissions to, as `toprint.pdf`. (If setting up a printer is too tricky, you *could* just save a PDF to that location. *grumble grumble*)

Also have an `index.html` in your web server directory with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>wizzwizz4's print hack</title></head><body>
<iframe id="printframe" src="toprint.pdf"></iframe>
<script>
  var f = document.getElementById("printframe");
  f.onload = function(e) { f.focus(); f.contentWindow.print(); }
</script>
</body></html>
```

Then your process becomes:

1. Print to the pseudoprinter / save on top of `toprint.pdf` on your laptop.
2. Double-click on a shortcut on your desktop (this is a link to the web page on your laptop).
3. Click "Print" on the popup.
4. Close the extra browser window / tab.

If you're not logged on, you could ask a friend to do steps 2 through 4 for you to save more time (at the expense of some of theirs).